# xlocnum.h errors when including iostream

Tags: c++

I have some code, and when I don't include iostream everything works, but when I do, I get a bunch of strange errors:

[image]

I have never seen this before and don't know what this means...

edit:
The ambiguous symbol is unrelated btw, that's already fixed

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: visual studio express 2012

Comment: Is this the first time you are using this compiler?

Comment: no, far from the first time why?

Comment: Just wondering if you hadn't installed everything correctly.

Comment: Preprocess to a file with /P.  Find out what the xlocnum line got turn into, should give you an idea what macro caused the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

oke pretty dumb: defined a macro named size, which apparently causes conflicts all of the place:p

I wonder though, wouldn't it be pretty easy for a compiler to figure our whether string->size() should be interpreted as a method call or as string->4, which makes no sense...